# Net flux through insulating cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields

In a non-uniform electric field, say with field lines curving away from each other along x, will the net flux on a cylinder be negative or zero?

Answer (score 0):

Well that would depend on where you place your surface in relation to the sources.

In this example - the surface is not a cylinder but still - the net flux is $0$ since the surface does not enclose any source charges.  The flux through some smaller patches of the surface can be either positive or negative depending on the location of the patch.  [image]

but if the source charge was inside the surface there would be non-zero net flux, either positive or negative depending on the net charge, as per this example.[image]

[Image credit: Young and Freeman *University Physics*]